# How to use List type with Codable? (RealmSwift)

Tags: swift, realm, swift4

Problem is List type does not conform to Codable, the below class cannot be insert to Realm.

for example,

```
class Book: Codable {
    var name: String = ""
    var author: String = ""
    var tags = [String]()
}
```

Consider the above class conforms to Codable, if store this class to Realm, it needs to use `List<Object>` type instead of `[String]`

```
class Book: Object, Codable {
    @objc dynamic var name: String = ""
    @objc dynamic var author: String = ""
    var tags = List<Tag>()

    required convenience init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        self.init()
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        name = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .name)
        author = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .author)
        tags = try container.decode(List<Tag>.self, forKey: .tags)   // this is problem.
    }
}

class Tag: Object, Codable {
    @objc dynamic var string: String = ""

    required convenience init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        self.init()
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        string = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .string)
    }
}
```

To conform to Codable, it should be implement `Decodable` protocol. (`required convenience init(from decoder: Decoder) throws`)

But, `List` type does not conform to `Codable`(`Decodable`), it is impossible to use Codable if the class has `List` type.

How to resolve this issue?

Thanks,

Comment: Write an extension to List to make it conform to `Codable`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are almost there. Inside the initializer, you can initialize the list using the decoded array. Basically, change

```
tags = try container.decode(List<Tag>.self, forKey: .tags)   // this is problem.
```

to

```
let tagsArray = try container.decode([Tag].self, forKey: .tags)   
tags = List(tagsArray) // Now you are good
```

**As pointed out in the comments the `List` constructor no longer works like this**

You now want:

```
tags.append(objectsIn: tagsArray)
```

Comment: This constructor doesn't seem to exist in Realm 3.13.1

Answer (score 14):

We can use an extension to make List conform to Codable:

```
extension List : Decodable where Element : Decodable {
    public convenience init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        self.init()
        var container = try decoder.unkeyedContainer()
        while !container.isAtEnd {
            let element = try container.decode(Element.self)
            self.append(element)
        }
    } }

extension List : Encodable where Element : Encodable {
    public func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        var container = encoder.unkeyedContainer()
        for element in self {
            try element.encode(to: container.superEncoder())
        }
    } }
```

I also got an extension for RealmOptional, if others need.

> https://gist.github.com/ansonyao/41137bb3cbbca8ef31a13b6bc96ee422

Answer (score 4):

There is only one problem with the accepted answer. Realm specifies that lists should be `let`(Constants) So to modify the solution to follow best practices you just have to make your list a `let` and then loop through appending the results to your array.

```
// Change this Line in [Your Code]
// to a let (Constant)
```

`var tags = List<Tag>()` to `let tags = List<Tag>()`

Then change

```
tags = try container.decode(List<Tag>.self, forKey: .tags)
```

to

```
let tagsArray = try container.decode([Tag].self, forKey: .tags)   
tagsArray.forEach{ tags.append($0) }
```

Comment: nice answer, one question though: If we are appending the tags to the list here, will there be any chance of old tags being kept if the object is being reused somehow?

Comment: I don't think there is a chance of that since this is only run on the `init`. The `tagsArray` is instantiated as a new empty `Array` Now if you have another method that lets you append to this `tagsArray` you would have all the existing tags that are already there and if you did that you would probably want a method that would let you remove tags also. But I think generally you should be safe

Comment: Should probably use `tags.append(objectsIn: tagsArray)` instead of `tagsArray.forEach...`

Answer (score 4):

This is how you create your Realm / Swift 4 Codable Models.

For more Details with JSON Response, Model & URLSession: [Read this article](https://medium.com/@Kaakati/swift-4-codable-realm-database-list-59887a3fd4a4)

```
import RealmSwift

class VendorsList : Object, Decodable {
    @objc dynamic var id : Int = 0
    @objc dynamic var name : String?
    @objc dynamic var logo : String?
    // Create your Realm List.
    var kitchensList = List<VendorKitchens>()

    override class func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "id"
    }

    private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id
        case name
        case logo
        // Set JSON Object Key
        case kitchensList = "kitchens"

    }

    public required convenience init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        self.init()
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        self.id = try container.decode(Int.self, forKey: .id)
        self.name = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .name)
        self.logo = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .logo)
        // Map your JSON Array response
        let kitchens = try container.decodeIfPresent([VendorKitchens].self, forKey: .kitchensList) ?? [VendorKitchens()]
        kitchensList.append(objectsIn: kitchens)

    }

}


class VendorKitchens : Object, Decodable {
    @objc dynamic var id : Int = 0
    @objc dynamic var name : String?

    override class func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "id"
    }

    private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id
        case name
    }
}
```

Comment: This is Decodable not Codable! If you could use Codable you would get error: "Type 'VendorsList' does not conform to protocol 'Encodable'". And list should be let not var.