# Realm Subquery to filter data from 1 table w.r.t table 2

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, realm, realm-mobile-platform

Suppose that I have two models and corresponding tables in the Realm Database

```
public class Customer :Object {
   dynamic var  Id : String = ""
   dynamic var  NAME : String = ""
   dynamic var  Address : String = ""

   override public class func primaryKey() -> String? {
      return "Id"
   }  
}


public class Bills :Object {
    dynamic var  Id : String = ""
    dynamic var  Amount : String = ""
    dynamic var  CustomerId : String = ""

    override public class func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "Id"
    }
}
```

> **What I am doing:** I am getting list of All customers easily by doing
>   this

```
realmObj.objects(Customer.self)
```

> **What I want:** I want to do followings.

**I want to get all the list of Customers but I also want that the list contain such customer on top who purchases items more often. I mean I want the list ordering on the basis of customers that purchases more time from our shop. For this I can get it from the customer Id in Bills tables. 
But I do not know how to do it in Realm.**

I know it can be done through subquery but I am not getting how to do it in Realm. Please tell me what will be query/Predicate here to get the desired results.

Comment: As it is, there is no formal *relationship* between the two objects. I see you are storing the *CustomerId* on the bill but that's just a string, not a relationship. You should review [Relationships](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#relationships) in the docs. Secondly, your objective is vague - *customers that purchases more time*. What does that mean - actual number of purchases over a specified time? Or qty of items purchased over time? And to do that, you would need to store a timestamp so for example, you could query for all customers that had more than 5 bills in the last six months.

Comment: The initial idea was that the Bills table will save Id of customers who purchases any product from shop. so we can query on most number of repeated Id of customer in the Bills table to know that specific customer lets call it customer 34  purchases more things lets say his Id resides in that table 44 times. and Customer 2 purchases 2nd most so his id Resides 40 times in Bills tables

Comment: I already read those relations but did not figure out how thy will help me

Comment: I think it will make your life easier to hold a variable in your Customer class named `totalBillsCount`

Comment: I did not get you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have two answers but there are a couple of things to address first.

For both of your classes, if you want them to be managed by Realm you need to include @objc before each var you want managed

```
public class Customer :Object {
   @objc dynamic var  Id : String = ""
```

or optionally add @objcMembers to the class name

```
@objcMembers class Customer :Object {
       dynamic var  Id : String = ""
```

The other thing is that class properties (vars) should always be lower case, class names should start with upper case. Nothing should be all CAPS.

```
public class Customer :Object {
   @objc dynamic var  customer_id : String = ""
   @objc dynamic var  name : String = ""
```

First solution is using your current structure:

```
var topCustomers = [(String, Int)]() //stores the customer id and count in an array of tuples
let results = realm.objects(Bills.self) //get all the bills
let allCustomerIds = results.map{ $0.CustomerId } //get a list of all of the customer id's
let uniqueIds = Set(allCustomerIds) //create a set of unique customer ids

for custId in uniqueIds { //iterate over the array of unique customer id's
    let count = results.filter("CustomerId == %@", custId).count // get a count of each customer id from results
    topCustomers.append( (custId, count) ) //add the customer id and it's count to the array
}

topCustomers.sort { $0.1 > $1.1 } //sort the array by count
for x in topCustomers { //print out the array - the customer with the most bills will be at the top
    print(x.0, x.1)
}
```

a second, more elegant approach uses a relationship between customers and their bills. This will provide a LOT more flexibility for generating reports, queries and overall organization.

Here's the updated classes:

```
class CustomerClass: Object {
   @objc dynamic var  customer_id = UUID().uuidString
   @objc dynamic var  name = ""
   @objc dynamic var  address = ""

   let billList = List<BillClass>()

   override public class func primaryKey() -> String? {
      return "customer_id"
   }
}

class BillClass: Object {
    @objc dynamic var  bill_id = UUID().uuidString
    @objc dynamic var  amount = ""

    override public class func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "bill_id"
    }
}
```

and then some very short code to accomplish the same thing as in the first example

```
let customers = realm.objects(CustomerClass.self) //get all customers
let results = customers.map { ($0.name, $0.billList.count) } //iterate over all, creating tuple with customer name & bill count
let sortedResults = results.sorted(by: { $0.1 > $1.1} ) //sort by bill count, descending
sortedResults.forEach { print($0) } //print the results, customer will most bills at top
```

Notes the use of UUID().uuidString

```
@objc dynamic var  bill_id = UUID().uuidString
```

creates unique primary keys for your objects. Eliminates dealing with indexing, uniqueness, incrementing etc.

Comment: I have somehow accomplished same task using technique as you used in your Solution 1. secondly You have not used sub query also in your solution 2.. Why?
Realm does not allow SUBQUERY ?

Comment: @A.s.ALI Yes, Realm allows subquery but it's pretty limited (IMO) and we also needed sorting which can't be done directly for this use case. The second approach was very simple and short code so it didn't appear to be needed in that case.

Comment: Thanks Jay, but can you help me with this question ? 
https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/398995/mobile-applications-and-database-sync-with-server

Comment: @A.s.ALI I am going to reply here. That question, while I get what you are asking, is very vague and starting to get downvotes. You should clarify the question and provide a better use case. i.e. If you were using Firebase, the changes made by use A would automatically sync up to the server when the connection was reestablished. If you were using Realm, it would also behave in a similar fashion. If you're using MySQL, it won't happen without additional resources. MongoDB can sync as well. See? Lots of different answers so the question needs to be more specific.

Comment: In iOS I am using realm, and on android I am using green dao.  and on server side i am using MySql db.  so I want that my web,android and ios device remain in sync if user is logged in 3 different device like in web, ios mobile and android

Comment: @A.s.ALI When responding to a comment please ensure to include the at symbol keyword so it will get that users attention, Otherwise they won't know you responded to a comment. See how I put the at symbol with your name at the beginning of this response? You need to include more information in that question, not here.  I can only address Realm but that will sync automatically as long as your are using Realm Cloud/Realm Sync. The other two I am not familiar with. The docs for Realm are here [Realm Sync](https://docs.realm.io/sync/)